# Laravel 4: After checking "remember me" checkbox user's login doesn't get remembered in database, only in cookie, thus remember me not working

Tags: php, cookies, laravel-4

I am using laravel 4.1.24.

I have a login form where i am trying to implement the remember me functionality. I have used Auth::attempt() to implement the above. Here's my code.

```
$input = Input::all();

$rules = array('email' => 'required', 'password' => 'required');

$v = Validator::make($input, $rules);

if($v->passes()) {

   $credentials = array('email' => $input['email'], 'password' => $input['password']);

   if( Auth::attempt($credentials, Input::has('remember_me') ? true : false) ) {

      // user authenticated
   }
} else {

      return Redirect::to('login')->withInput()->withErrors($v);
}
```

I have also created a column "remember_token"(a nullable string with 255 chars) in users table. And also added below 3 methods in the model User.php

```
public function getRememberToken()
{
    return $this->remember_token;
}

public function setRememberToken($value)
{
    $this->remember_token = $value;
}

public function getRememberTokenName()
{
    return 'remember_token';
}
```

Yes it does sets the cookie named remember_xxxxxx, but it doesn't add anything to the remember_token column. It's not working. Is there something i missed ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am using laravel 4.1.24.

The `remember_token` value was introduced in Laravel 4.1.26. You need to upgrade your version to take advantage of the new functionality. [Here is an upgrade guide from the Laravel Docs for you](http://laravel.com/docs/upgrade).